# Confusion in assignment in c

Tags: c, variable-assignment, conditional-operator, postfix-mta, postfix-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a=0, b=1, c=3;
 *((a) ?&b :&a) = a ? b : c; 
 printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
 return 0;
}
```

**Output:3 1 3**

The associativity for assignment operator is right to left . So here we got 3 1 3 but ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a=0, b=1, c=3;
 *((a++) ?&b :&a) = a ? b : c;
 printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
 return 0;
}
```

**Output : 1 1 3**

```
My doubt is why 1 1 3 is returned instead of 1 3 3 ?
```

Answer (score 6):

What you have here is a manifestation of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Order of operations only dictate how operands are grouped.  It does *not* dictate the order in which subexpressions are evaluated.

In this expression:

```
*((a++) ?&b :&a) = a ? b : c;
```

The only guarantee is that `a++` will be evaluated before either `&b` or `&a`, and that `a` will be evaluated before either `b` or `c`.  There is **no** sequencing between the evaluation of `a++` and `a`, so you have a read and a write of a variable without a sequence point.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, I missed that.  Fixed.